# Blocked errors in google webmaster for SMARTPHONE

Tags: google-search-console

I am getting blocked errors in GWT for smartphones. All blocked error pages which is showing in GWT already disallowed from robots.txt. But I don't why GWT showing these page in blocked errors (**Smartphone**).

**Using in Robots.txt:**

User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

These errors are mainly due to the desktop version of the pages being blocked by robots.txt

Examine the robots.txt ...which clearly shows it is blocked for smartphones as well

For more details..

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4066608?hl=en&ref_topic=2446029